# Differences between PSObject and PSAdapted

Tags: powershell, scripting

Can somebody explain to me (no links, just use their own words) what are the differences in usage between PSObject and PSAdapted?

Comment: I'm not sure what's expected of my question. I did not ask for code. I just asked for a plain explanation of a Powershell programming concept because the existing documentation is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To begin with, PSAdapted is a member of the PSObject class.

PSObject is an object abstraction (wrapper) through which PowerShell lets you access all kinds of objects in a consistent and unified way.

The PSObject class contains several intrinsic members sets, three of which are:

- PSBase  - Provides access to the members of the base object (the object being wrapped. e.g PSObject.BaseObject)
- PSAdapted - Contains the members added via PowerShell extended type system (ETS).
- PSExtended - Provides access just the extended members added to the base object (via ps1xml files or by the Add-Member cmdlet).

Hope this helps.